# MySQL ANALYZE TABLE Response

Tags: mysql, database

Anyone any suggestion on what's the difference between these in an `ANALYZE TABLE <tablename>` response?

```
Msg_type: status
Msg_text: OK
```

and

```
Msg_type: status
Msg_text: Table is already up to date
```

I always get the same response on the same tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `Table is already up to date` means t there was no need to check the table.
- `Msg_text: OK` means your operation was successful.

In both cases, nothing is wrong with your engine or anything else.